# How can both generator and discriminator losses decrease?

Tags: deep-learning, gan, generative-models

In [this](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5f69/d59ad195a69618231ad83c4ad6342a569074.pdf) paper there is a plot of how the loss of gans looks through epochs.

Figure 2:

[image: figure 2]

These are of course averaged losses.

How can both the discriminator loss and generator loss decrease?

```
real_y = discriminator(real_sample)
fake_y = discriminator(generator(noise))
discriminator_loss = real_y-fake_y+1 # nicer, it is between 0 and 2

fake_y = discriminator(generator(noise))
generator_loss = fake_y
```

I would expect one of the losses to increase as the other one decreases. Since they use the same calculation of `fake_y` and one decreases `-fake_y` and the other `fake_y`. One optimizer is making `fake_y` less and the other optimizer is making it more.

Maybe the loss functions aren't calculated like I said.

In the widely used analogy:

> In simple terms the generator is like a forger trying to produce some counterfeit material, and the discriminator is like the police trying to detect the forged items.

We can measure how good the police is by how many times out of 100 fakes he can identify the real and fake ones and the forger as deceiving the policeman out of 100 fakes.

Wouldn't that mean that if the police get better, the forger gets worse? (if using the aforementioned measure of how good they are)

Therefore we wouldn't be able to see both of them being good at the same time! But the graph from the paper indicates otherwise.

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe both discriminator and generator are overfitting, able to fit new batch well.

Answer (score 3):

In the subsection of the figure, they compute the average loss across 100 iterations, which is why the loss is monotonically decreasing because on average the loss does decrease with the training.

You are correct in inferring that if this was reported on an iteration to iteration basis, the loss would be a zig zag curve, which is less nice to look at than a smooth curve.

As in the comments, the loss *can* monotonically decrease to 0, if it is the Wasserstein distance. The Wasserstein distance is computed as $\sup_{f \in L_{k}} E_{x \sim P_X}[f] - E_{x \sim P_{\theta}} [f]$ where the first term is the expectation of the function, $f$ (discriminator) over the batch and the second term is the generated data from the generator computed on the discriminator. Note that by this formulation, it returns the $k$-Wasserstein distance.

Comment: Good answer - the devil is in the details, but still an interesting observation on a batch-by-batch basis from the OP.

Comment: Certainly! @n1k31t4, I find the concept of GAN's to be very fascinating, although I do not know much about it

Comment: I realize that it would be less smooth but I don't understand how the two loss functions can both decrease (even when averaged). I would expect one of the losses to increase as the other one decreases. Since they use the same calculation of `fake_y` and one decreases `-fake_y` and the other `fake_y`.

Comment: The goal of the training is to find the minimum loss function, so the optimizer optimizes both the discriminator and the generator simultaneously.

Comment: How are people up voting this answer? It has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Even for a typical GAN across iterations you should the loss zig-zag depending on whether the discriminator or the generator are winning. The question refers to why the loss monotonically moves -- and the answer is that this is an average loss across multiple iterations.

Comment: @PSub This question IS NOT asking anything about zig-zagging or why it is monotonic. The OP even specified this in the comments. The question is how can both losses continue to decrease over time like this, which is impossible in a regular GAN. This has absolutely nothing to do with whether it is averaged or not to create smoothing. OP said they understand this. When a normal GAN converges the loss for the generator and discriminator will be at 50% error. One can't go higher without the other going lower. They don't tend towards zero unless it's a WGan.

Comment: Okay, let me break this apart piece by piece. First, even in a regular GAN the training loss DOES decrease over time until it converges to a mixed strategy nash equilibrium. This has nothing to do with whether the Wasserstein metric is used or not, this is simply a result of stochastic optimization and a minimization of the loss. Similarly, this happens in W-GAN as well but the loss landscape is supposedly much smoother which makes training easier. Finally, the error is not a binary metric, it is a variant of the minimax loss which can decrease over time.

Comment: I don't know what kind of GANs you are training but in every one of the countless GANs I've used the losses for G and D move towards whatever the loss is (depends on loss function) when there is 50% accuracy (D predicts correctly 50% of the time, G fools D 50% of the time). They absolutely do not tend towards 0. You have a major error if you are seeing that happen. This is not the case in a WGan.

Comment: Re-read what I wrote above, the error doesn't move towards 0. But it does move towards a local optimum. This is what is the mixed strategy nash equilibrium guarantees. I never said that the loss should be at 0, which is odd -- however, it could be a caveat of how the loss is defined in their particular case. If you are arguing about the nash equilibrium being *at* 0, then sure, maybe there might be an issue -- but if you are saying that they do not trend downwards, it might be worth re-reading what the GAN loss is.

Comment: You said in your answer that the loss decreases with training. This is not true and does not answer the question. The loss moves towards the equilibrium which could be higher or lower. In a stable GAN the graph for the losses has no trend up or down. It should stay pretty flat the whole time.  This is in contrast to W loss where both losses decrease over time. That's where the OP's confusion comes from. The black and blue lines make no sense for a traditional GAN

Comment: In the image, all of the losses decrease over time -- if you observe the ends of the graphs. If you're talking about why the W-GAN can reach 0, then, yes, this is indeed a fact of the wasserstein metric. I can append this fact to my answer if that is where we disagree.

Answer (score -1):

This is because the discriminator in WGan isn't a classifier and works differently from the traditional GAN.
You are 100% correct that in a normal GAN it wouldn't make any sense for both losses to decrease as shown.

Comment: This isn't true -- despite the WGAN having a different loss function, namely the Wasserstein distance, one should still not expect that the discriminator and generator simultaneously monotonically increase -- generally one of them "wins" the round and receives a lower portion of the loss.

Comment: @PSub You are completely misunderstanding the question. It's not a question about the small scale changes of the loss values. OP is asking how they can both move towards zero when one is defined as the inverse of the other. It's because in a WGan the losses are not defined this way. This is one of the useful qualities of the W distance cited in the paper - the loss actually means something about how well the network is converging. In a normal GAN this is not the case.

Comment: There are a couple of things that are wrong here. You're right that the Wasserstein metric is indicative of the distance between two distributions. But I think you misunderstand that GANs cannot have a monotonically decrease the loss -- if the generator improves faster than the discriminator deteriorates, you would have a reducing loss. Maybe, we're disagreeing about semantics here, but I'm not sure -- if you look carefully at the figure, the GAN loss also decreases -- are you saying this is incorrect?

Comment: Even in the figure G and D are roughly inversely proportionate. There is a lot of noise because at each point in the graph you are measuring their loss for a small sample, but in general as one goes up you see the other go down. As I said one of the nice things about W loss is it doesn't behave this way. That's one of the main things this graph is showing. The losses are interpretable unlike in a normal Gan.

Comment: I don't think we're disagreeing about the Wasserstein metric having the capability of decrease to 0. I think what we're disagreeing about is whether the GAN loss _can_ decrease at all. From your comments above it seems like you think that it _cannot_ which is patently false. I agree that it decreasing to 0 is indeed confusing, but I would need to read their code before concluding it's an error.

Comment: The loss for G or D can trend downwards in a normal GAN, but only if the other trends upwards. They can't both just continue to decrease in the long run. How well G is doing is based on how bad D is doing. Two things that are inversely proportional can't continuously decrease.

Comment: They cannot indeed decrease to 0, unless specified by a loss that allows for it, however, your answers seem to assume that the total GAN Loss cannot decrease at all. This is where we disagree, and you are quite mistaken about the loss being able to decrease at all. The continuous decrease _can_ happen until it reaches a stable equilibrium, at which point it will stabilize.